# Worklight console login screen not showing

Tags: authentication, console, ibm-mobilefirst, screen

I have deployed my worklight server 6.1 in WebSphere Application server liberty profile. And i have created the server configuration for application.

Now My console is opening with out login. kindly suggest how to enable login feature for My worklight console.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project's .war file contains the configuration for username/password, as detailed in the following documentation topic: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_protecting_ibm_worklight_console.html